# Google play store IAP Billing unavailable for this package and user

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

We are developing an app with IAP Items with google play store, On Some devices, we can't make the paying page show, and from the logcat there is :

```
2020-01-02 20:23:46.291 16104-16155/com.mycompany.myapp I/UnityIAP: Starting in-app billing setup.
2020-01-02 20:23:46.319 16104-16104/com.mycompany.myapp I/UnityIAP: Billing service connected.
2020-01-02 20:23:46.325 16104-16320/com.mycompany.myapp I/UnityIAP: invoking callback
2020-01-02 20:23:46.325 16104-16320/com.mycompany.myapp I/UnityIAP: Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
2020-01-02 20:23:46.341 12886-13114/com.android.vending I/Finsky: [2139] gcv.d(3): com.mycompany.myapp: Account determined from installer data - [tvj6t7d7SJBbFycvTAtq3A9mYaQ3F08RzOqtlSgP5J8]
2020-01-02 20:23:46.341 12886-13114/com.android.vending I/Finsky: [2139] gcv.d(14): com.mycompany.myapp: Account from preferred account - [tvj6t7d7SJBbFycvTAtq3A9mYaQ3F08RzOqtlSgP5J8]
2020-01-02 20:23:46.356 12886-13114/com.android.vending W/Finsky: [2139] gcg.a(357): Billing unavailable for this package and user.
```

What could possibly cause this problem?

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Please let me know for solution.

Comment: @ChiragPrajapati it's an account issue, it's seems google play IAP will refuse to work once the account has multi-payment methods

Comment: I have the same issue both in my two devices. I am not sure if it is account related.

Comment: @armnotstrong Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ayyappa it was an account issue, problem solved after changing to another google play account.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. After configuring everything according to the Google guidelines (app was published in the Internal test track and the account was added to the list of testers), I had to wait several hours to get the list of sku. In fact, I got the list the next day.